# Stop firefox from caching stuff even though I've told it not to

Tags: firefox, caching

Working on a site and when opening a page the new css is not used. Press F12 (firebug) in the css tab select the css file and see it's not the one that's on the server.

Right click on the file in firebug and choose "open in new tab" now I see the file as it's actually on the server.

I have created a new profile in firefox with the following settings:
tools -> options -> privacy -> use custom settings for history -> checked "clear histoty when firefox closes" click on the button next to it called settings checked everything there (including cache) hoping that absolutely nothing is saved. Restart the browser but still cached.

This profile I've created is started with:

```
C:\>"Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -p -no-remote
```

In the firefox net tab I can see the request to the css being made and in the response I do see the new css file but in the CSS tab when I select the file then the old one is showing. It's definetely Firefox stubbronly holding on to this file even though the net tab shows it's being requested and loaded. It's not some proxy caching it for me because the net tab in firebug shows the new css file.

**[UPDATE]**
Solved this problem, will add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making sure Firefox doesn't cache anything you have to set it not to remember anything. This is best done in a separate profile. Start Firefox with the following options:

```
C:\>"Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -p -no-remote
```

Create a new profile and start it. When started do the following: tools -> options -> privacy -> use custom settings for history -> check "clear history when firefox closes" click on the button next to it called "settings" check everything there (including cache).

Now before opening a page press control + shift + k to open dev tools.

Click on the network tab and load or reload the page. When it's done loading click on the css file you are interrested in. In the right pane you can see request and response headers you can see if you got a fresh file or from cache (proxies can cache too).

To see what's been loaded you can check on the right pane "response" button.

When you see that the right css is actually loaded then click on the console tab/button.

You can filter the output by clicking the other buttons (NET, CS, JS, Security,Logging) and show only css warnings or errors. Next to the CSS button is a little arrow down, click on that and make sure it shows both warnings and errors.

My problem was a syntax error in the existing css, I've pasted new values at the end but somewhere in the file was something like this:

```
IMG: {
```

No closing } was given.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

there are many examples already available on stackoverflow.Please do a search.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I posted this question because I thought Firefox was taking values from cache even though it wasn't supposed to. If you've read the question you'd see that firebug showed the fresh file was fetched but firebug css tab doesn't show the new values. This was because there was no closing `}` in the css file so when I pasted my code at the end it didn't show up in the CSS panel of firebug because it wasn't parsed. The complete file shows up in the net tab because that shows the complete response (not the parsed one)